# Help in proving limit as x approaches infinity

Tags: limits

I know how to do A. but included it for completion. I'm stuck on b because while proving i can't find a way not to eliminate x. No matter what algebra tricks i play the x cancels out and I'm left with no x.

A. Prove lim ((x+1)^(1/2)-(x)^(1/2))=0 as x approaches infinity.
B. Show lim ((x^2+x)^(1/2)-(x))=1/2 as x approaches infinity.
(Hint: for A. Multiply numerator and denominator by ((x+1)^(1/2)+(x)^(1/2)) and treat B. similarly.

Answer (score 1):

$$A.\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+1-x}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt x}=\cdots$$

$$B.\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+x}-x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2+x-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{1+\dfrac1x}+1}=\cdots $$

---

Alternatively,  setting $x=\dfrac1h$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+x}-x)=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+h}-1}h$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{(1+h)-1}{h(\sqrt{1+h}+1)}$$

Now we can safely cancel out $h$ as $h\ne0$ as $h\to0$

Try out the same method for the first limit